# ADB media playback status

Tags: android, adb

I am able to start a MP3 playback by using command

`am start -W -n com.android.music/com.android.music.MediaPlaybackActivity -d /mp3file.mp3`

I would like to loop mp3 continuously so that I don't have to start it again.
For that there is no command to enable looping from adb shell.
So I would like to ask if there is a way to check if MP3 playback is in progress from ADB without modifying the Android code?

I tried `dumpsys audio`, but it shows `MediaPlaybackActivity` even if the MP3 playing has stopped.
Is there  a way to find out if MediaplaybackActivity is actually playing MP3 or just stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could pass extras to the Activity to loop the music, there is no REAL way to control the behavior behind the Activity from adb unless you add the necessary hooks.

### Details

https://developer.android.com/tools/help/shell.html

Comment: can you please tell how to pass extras?

Comment: I checked [http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html), but cannot find how to add looping option by setting an argument

Comment: @Raj Please stop depending on tutorials to tell you everything. Read the documentation. The documentation you should read is @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: here [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) it gives information about `setLooping` function. But trying to understand how to use it.

Comment: Once you understand the APIs, building the hooks should be easy.